# regexprep function not able to accept \b to find number range

Tags: regex, string, matlab, replace

I am attempting to use regular expression substitution for the following types of strings:

```
'y = 0'
'y = 10'
'y = 23'
```

I want the replacement to return the number only if it lies between 1 and 22. (i.e. less than 1 and greater than 22 will return some other result)

I have it written as follows, and I cannot understand why this won't work:

```
regexprep('y = 5', 'y = '\b([1-9]$|1[0-9]|2[0-2])\b', '$1')
```

Is there something I am missing about syntax here? I find that if I remove the `\b` I can get the proper result for:

```
regexprep('y = 0', 'y = ([1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-2])', '$1')
```

i.e. no change, and for the numbers from 1-22 I get the right result, but then all numbers greater than 22 are also getting replaced by `$1` as well. I have no idea why. Any help would be great. Thanks.

Comment: Why not extract the number at the end  of the string (say, with `num = regexp(your_string,'[0-9]+(?=\s*$)','match')`) and then compare if it is between 1 and 22 using regular language means (`str2num`)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
regexprep(y = 5', 'y = '\b([1-9]$|1[0-9]|2[0-2])\b', '$1')
```

This isn't legal MATLAB syntax for strings.  They need to be encompassed in single quotes.  But that was probably just a typo.  The real issue is that \b in MATLAB's regular expressions means [backspace](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/regular-expressions.html), not blank as in traditional regular expressions.

```
regexprep('y = 0', 'y = ([1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-2])', '$1')
```

This needs an end-of-line $.

```
regexprep('y = 0', 'y = ([1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-2])$', '$1')
```

Better yet, allow flexible spacing:

```
regexprep('y = 0', 'y\s*=\s*([1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-2])$', '$1')
```

Comment: Thanks, I fixed the typo. And the replace function works great. Thanks for helping with that!

Answer (score 2):

Use Regex: `^y\s=\s(?:[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-2])$`

and use the `regexp` function in place of `regexprep` as mentioned [here](https://it.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/regexp.html#expand_panel_heading_btpdzh5-1_1)

```
matchStr = regexp('y = 1','^y\s=\s(?:[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-2])$','match')
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/lMv7rb/2)